# Install a service created with .NET using WiX

Tags: c#, windows-services, wix

I am trying to create a service using VS2012 express that will be installed with WiX.  This is done without the templates provided in the full version of VS.  I had my class derive from ServiceBase.  I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that if the program was installed using WiX that a class derived from ServiceInstaller was not necessary.  When I run the MSI that is created by WiX, no errors are flagged, but no new service shows up.

I have Google searched for an answer, but didn't find an example of the miniumum C# code needed to create a service.  Links to a good tutorial or pointing out the area where either the C# or WiX code is lacking would be appreciated.

The code for the template service is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace WixInstalledServiceTeamplate
{
    class BasicService : ServiceBase
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        public BasicService()
        {
            this.AutoLog = true;
            this.ServiceName = "MY Service Template";

        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);

            //TODO: place your start code here
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();

            //TODO: clean up any variables and stop any threads
        }

    }
}
```

Wix Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="786F7069-9C7F-4E15-A721-6B3B4D300FD9" Name="WixEditText" Language="1033" Version="0.0.0.1" Manufacturer="3M Automated Inpsection and Measurement" UpgradeCode="31956530-98A2-4C83-B3A9-5FB6B7A7AE07">
        <Package Description="Test file in a Product" Comments="Simple test" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="simple.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
                <Directory Id="RELEASE" Name="Release">
                    <Component Id="WIXINSTALLEDSERVICETEAMPLATE.EXE" DiskId="1" Guid="B0AEF920-4EF0-478C-9B5A-0B13F23F7E73">
                        <File Id="WIXINSTALLEDSERVICETEAMPLATE.EXE" Name="WixInstalledServiceTeamplate.exe" Source="bin\Release\WixInstalledServiceTeamplate.exe" />
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
        <Feature Id="Complete" Title="Install Everything" Level="1" Display="expand" ConfigurableDirectory="TARGETDIR">
            <Component Id="MYServiceTemplate" Guid="1BD8DA93-86A6-4DC4-8CE9-B59525DDFB89" Directory="TARGETDIR">
                <ServiceInstall Name="myservicetemplate" Type="ownProcess" Start="demand" ErrorControl="normal" Account="LOCAL SYSTEM" Description="test service install with wix" DisplayName="MY Service Template" Id="serviceInstall">
                </ServiceInstall>
            </Component>
            <ComponentRef Id="WIXINSTALLEDSERVICETEAMPLATE.EXE" />
        </Feature>
        <UI />
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption that only ServiceBase is needed is correct.  However you only need 1 component not 2 components in WiX.  The ServiceInstall doesn't reference a file, it implicitly applies to the keyfile of the parent component.

If you need the ability to install the EXE and a console app and/or a service (variation point) that gets more complicated. The easiest is to factor into a DLL and create 2 EXE's with a total of 3 components.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I now need to search for 'factor into a DLL'.  I had been using srvany to make an exe into a service, apparently I will need to modify 'something' to create a service dll.

Comment: Windows Installer (and therefore WiX) makes it difficult to create a component (FOO.EXE) that may or may not be a service.  The easiest thing to do is make a FooConsoleApp.exe and FooService.exe where the former is not a service and the latter is a service.  Then to promote code reuse you take the common code and move it into FooLibrary.dll.   Make sense?

Comment: It's technically possible to create a single Foo.exe that may or may not be a service but it involves a lot of complexity on the installer side around components with mutually exclusive conditions and what not.  Ugly stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the KeyFile tip.